# Why is my processor underused when I perform calculation intensive simulations?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I often have to run calculation intensive simulations using Matlab. These simulations often take a long time and I expect my computer to use all its ressources in order for these simulations to be completed in as little time as possible.

However, when I open the Activity Monitor on my computer, **processor usage** is **never above 55%** and there is often about 1GB of unused RAM.

My question is: **why** is the processor not used to its full potential, and is there a safe and easy way to change this? Indeed, it would be great if I could get my simulations to be completed in half the time they currently take!

Comment: It's dual core, but whatever the number of cores, why aren't they fully used?

Comment: I'm in complete agreement with @slayton (+1). I started using `parfor` loops in my simulations a couple of months back, and am now able to get all 4 cores in my machine up to 100%. There's some overhead with `parfor` though - I get (approximately) a 2.5 times speed, not a 4 times speedup. Regarding RAM, Matlab typically uses as much as it needs, as opposed to as much as you have. If it needs more than you have, you'll know about it as run-time will suddenly get about 100 times slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its probably because you have a processer with multiple cores and that the code you are executing isn't written to run in multiple threads/processes.  Unless you specifically write your code to take advantage of multiple cores it will only be able to use a single core at a single time.

A relatively easy way to enable parallel computing is to use the [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/).

Additionally you might consider reading this: http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/parallel-matlab-multiple-processors-and-multiple-cores.html